# How do I integrate my web app with One Drive so that users don't have to log in twice?

Tags: single-sign-on

We want to deeply integrate OneDrive with our web app in order to handle document and storage data. However, we want the users not to log in twice. I'm not sure whether this is possible, but I've been reading about SSO and SAML and it seems like it's the way to go.

Is it possible, and if so, is Single Sign On the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single Sign-On (SSO) is a great solution for user experience when web applications are hosted on different domains. SAML as a standard was developed for cross domain authentication to solve this use case. You will need an Identity Provider (IdP) server that handles authentication of users to your web application and then the IdP Server issues SAML assertions to your web application and OneDrive. Your application in this architecture will be a Service Provider (SP) that will consume SAML assertions, as well as OneDrive is a SP that consumes SAML assertions. There are a number of SSO/Federation vendors that provide the IdP Server.

As far as implementation, once you have chosen and installed the IdP Server, you will need to implement your web application to consume the SAML assertion and configure the IdP Server as a connection.  OneDrive will simply be a configuration as it already supports SAML and WS-Federation.

In addition to SAML as a protocol, there are other standards with respect to SSO/Federation such as OpenID Connect (OIDC) and OAuth2. When choosing a IdP Server solution you may want to look at these other protocols that can solve additional use cases.  SAML works well for web applications and the use case you have described. OIDC and OAuth2 are better suited for secure APIs and native mobile applications.

Another consideration when looking at an IdP Server is how authentication is to be performed. Options for authentication could be using Kerberos/IWA if all clients are on a common domain, or authentication using a Login Form. You may also want to look at MFA support when looking at an IdP Server as part of the SSO solution.